# Redirect to site from link in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

i am trying to redirect my page to Google from a link in Extjs

Here is the code:

```
Ext.create("Ext.Component", {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
autoEl: {
html: "Link",
href: "www.google.co.in",
tag: "a"
}
});
```

But instead of redirecting to page it is looking for a file in the working folder.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Ext.create("Ext.Component", {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    autoEl: {
        html: "Link",
        href: "http://www.google.co.in",
        tag: "a",
        target: "_blank"
    }
});
```

It does go to a new window, so you you could just remove the target config if you need to.

Comment: You should emphasise the importance of the protocol in the URL in your answer, as broadly speaking this problem hasn't actually got anything to do with ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open new url in same tab than another option is to put this line in click handler

```
window.document.location="http://google.com"
```

This will open page in same browser tab.